# Wicket 8.x Excel download link not working and showing 404 error

Tags: java, spring, wicket, wicket-8

I have upgraded Wicket 1.x to wicket 8.x. After this upgrade Excel and PDF download stop working and showing 404 error.

I have found this below class has been removed after the wicket 1.5 version.

```
      org.apache.wicket.markup.html.DynamicWebResource
```

And this below class is the replacement of this class

```
      org.apache.wicket.request.resource.ByteArrayResource
```

Are there any tutorials or demo on how to do this in Wicket 8.x version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usage is something like this:

```
ResourceReference ref = new ResourceReference() {
  @Override
  public IResource getResource() {
     byte[] theExcelFileAsBytes = ...;
     return new  new ByteArrayResource("application/msexcel", theExcelFileAsBytes, "fileName.xsl");
  }
};

ResourceLink<Void> link = new ResourceLink<>("linkId", ref);
parent.add(link);
```

Here is an [article](http://wicketinaction.com/2011/07/wicket-1-5-mounting-resources/) about mounting resources at specific paths. You can use `ExternalLink` to link to such resource[reference].

Comment: Hi @martin-g, that shared article link is related to the Wicket 1.5 implementation which is deprecated in my case. I am looking to implement it in Wicket 8.5 version. Kindly suggest any solution for that?

Comment: The API must be the same in 1.5.x and 8.x for this particular need. Did you try it ? Did you face any issues ?!

Comment: Sorry I was missing one step. Now implemented your suggested code and now it is working fine for me. Thanks a lot, martin.